# ¿Cómo restauro un evento luego de usar unbind en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes queridos amigos de stackoverflow.

Mi problema es el siguiente he querido usar la función de jquery `unbind('click')` dentro de mi codigo para deshabilitar los click dentro de un determinado div pero esta dentro de una condición quisiera saber como puedo retornar al estado original los elementos asignados por esta misma función. He usado `bind('click')` pero no retorna el evento queda en pocas palabras inutilizable una vez cumplida la condición.

Aquí esta mi trozo de codigo para que entiendan mejor. ¡Gracias!

```
  if ($("#wrapper").hasClass('toggled')) {
     $("#page-content-wrapper_main").width("150%");
      $("#page-content-wrapper a").unbind('click');
    }else{
      $("#page-content-wrapper_main").width("100%");
      $("#page-content-wrapper a").on('click');
    }
```

En conclusión deseo usar unbind para quitar los eventos click de ese div y si deja la condición facilmente vuelva a su estado original todos las etiquetas **a** anidadas.

Answer (score 0):

debes pasarle en el segundo parámetro de ambos eventos el nombre de la función o la misma función como parámetro

si estas usando jquery desde su version 1.7 en usa los eventos `on` y `off`, sino sus equivalentes en versiones anteriores que son `bind` y `unbind`

por ejemplo

```
function clickFunction() {

}


if ($("#wrapper").hasClass('toggled')) {
    $("#page-content-wrapper a").off('click', clickFunction); 
} 
else {
    $("#page-content-wrapper a").on('click',clickFunction);
}
```

[mira el siguiente ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/49je8a6q/7/)

Comment: Lo estoy implementando y no me toma la función **off** ahora, no la toma en cuenta.

Comment: en consola muestra algún error? actualice mi respuesta con un ejemplo utilizando el código que puse anteriormente. en que contexto no te funciona el off?

Comment: Pues en que lo implemento y no me quita los eventos, en ese contexto. La razón supongo es porque ahora que implemento esa función no me tomma en cuenta la función off.

Comment: viste el ejemplo del link que puse? cuando llamas al if? cuando carga la pagina o en algun otro momento.. si lo usas cuando carga la pagina se ejecutara una vez sola y va a entrar unicamente en una de las dos condiciones en caso de que tenga o no la clase toggled el contenedor. lo cual no seria incorrecto que no funcione off en caso de que el contenedor no tenga la clase toggled

Comment: Si, ya vi el ejemplo y lo he implementado el día de hoy pero me toma la función `off` sin la llamada de función `clickFunction`. Lo he probado en la consola de chromium y acepta el comando `$("#page-content-wrapper a").off('click', clickFunction);` sin errores definiendo `clickFunction` valga la redundancia y aún  así no le presta atención.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver mi propia pregunta.

Una solución muy viable es manejarme por los `z-index` de tal manera de hacer una un div como una capa por debajo de un evento que no se desea que ocurra en un `click` en estos casos. Simplemente añadiendo una función css:

```
if(event){$("#page-content-wrapper_main a").css('z-index', '-5');}
else{$("#page-content-wrapper_main a").css('z-index', '');}
```